# How to install Venia PWA Theme on Magento 2.3 using cPanel on Dedicated Server?

Tags: magento, themes, magento2, progressive-web-apps, venia

I have used git to clone pwa-studio theme, but still unable to run commands like yarn install. Tried installing node.js/npm  but couldn't because I am on a dedicated server. From where do I install the pwa-studio theme without any error and how?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you,

You will see the pwa-studio directory in /var/www/html/mage0.
Enter into this directoy:

> cd pwa-studio/

Run

> yarn install

Specify the Magento backend server in .env file.

> cp packages/venia-concept/.env.dist packages/venia-concept/.env

Open this .env file and find MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL.

> MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://magento-2-local/" # your local path

Find the deployVeniaSampleData.sh file in
/var/www/html/mage0/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/ directory. and copy this
file in your Magento root directory. Now it must look like
/var/www/html/mage0/deployVeniaSampleData.sh Now run:

> bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh

After successful installation run:

> bin/magento setup:upgrade bin/magento
>
> indexer:reindex bin/magento
>
> cache:flush

Now go back to pwa-studio directory /var/www/html/mage0/pwa-studio and
start Server.

> yarn run build **or** sudo yarn run build

Run server, Use any of the following commands from the project root directory to start
the server:

> yarn run watch:venia
>   yarn run watch:all
>   yarn run build && npm run
>   stage:venia

Now browse the application, you will the application url on terminal like:

PWADevServer ready at https://magento-venia.local.pwadev:8001

Thanks,